# Find Element using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find an element in the website that i am trying to automate but am unable to figure out how to fetch a particular element. I have provided the html below. Please provide some inputs. Thanks.

< div id="Troy_combine" class="sign_in_flow sign_in_flow_overlay troy_overlay epc_modal big_dialog modal_display" > < h3 class="migration"> Welcome back.< /h3>< h3 class="normal">Welcome to Disneyland< / h3>< p class="migration">*It looks like you have a account that use the same address and password. Let’s combine them into a single account to make it easier to access both services.*< /p>

**Note: There are multiple "migration" classes. How will it know which one to pick up??**

I am trying to fetch the text shown in Italics. Help required

Selenium Webdriver with Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a cssSelector like so:

```
String itext = driver
    .findElement( By.cssSelector("div#Troy_combine p.migration")).getText();
```

Comment: There are multiple classes with name as "migration". I want to get text of the one having 'p' tag. I am getting element not found exception with above solution

Comment: Is the space there between 'combine' and 'p'? Now i am not getting any exception but the string is returned as blank

Comment: His code is correct.  What happens if you run this: `new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.cssSelector("div#Troy_combine p.migration"), "It looks like you have a account that use the same address and password. Let’s combine them into a single account to make it easier to access both services."))`

Comment: I get a timeoutexception when i follow your advice...one thing i want to point out....the full html has multiple 'div' tags. i have copied only the one that I am interested in...Can that be the issue? So I am dealing with multiple 'div' and multiple classes with same name.

Comment: the CSS path of the element is shown as below when using Firebug: html body.login div.ui-dialog div#Troy_combine.sign_in_flow p.migration

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesnt work. I am using String itext = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body.login div.ui-dialog div#Troy_combine.sign_in_flow p.migration")).getText();   and still it returns a blank string. I used xpath which i was trying to avoid but still no result. The code i pasted here is of an overlay that gets displayed on the existing page. I am able to get the text for elements on main page but not for overlay.

Comment: hey djangofan....your suggestion worked just fine...problem was with wait....i added some wait and now i am able to get it to work....feeling like a dumbo now :). Thanks for your help though

Comment: @vaibhav misra -  ok, that is a really common problem.  there are a bunch of different ways to handle that, such as using the "FluentWait" class.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting via classes and IDs are always the easiest and most reliable.  Do a `By.className("migration")`.

Answer (score 0):

`findElement(By.cssSelector("div.migration")).getText();`

I think you could select it by ID as well.